# Soundcloud JS SDK - SC.Connect() callback window can't close if App installed on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

The Soundcloud's JS SDK, SC.connect(); redirect to a callback window after auth.
Everything is working well on desk and mobile except if you have the soundcloud APP installed (on iOS);

the callback file:

```
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
      </head>
      <body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
        <b style="text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
      </body>
    </html>
```

If you have the app installed, SC.connect() open the app to check if you are logged in before authenticate and redirect you to the callback.
Then the window.opener of callback.html is not your window anymore (because the app opened it) and the window can't call the methods and close.

the console says:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'window.opener.SC')
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'window.opener.setTimeout')
```

Is there a way to reach my original window without modifying the soundcloud SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to bypass the opening of the app by using an iframe inside a modal:

```
        this.connect= function(){
            var url = "https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id="+conf.soundcloud.client_id+"&redirect_uri="+conf.url.base+"/soundcloud-callback.html"+"&response_type=token&scope=non-expiring";
            $('#sc-connect-modal').modal('show');
            $( "#sc-connect-modal .modal-body" ).html('<iframe height="500px" width="100%" frameBorder="0" src="'+url+'"></iframe>');
        };
```

my soundcloud-callback.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.setTimeout(window.parent.scCallback(window.location.hash), 1);">
    <b style="text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

the callback function:

```
        $window.scCallback = function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('#sc-connect-modal').modal('hide');
            response=response.replace('#','');
            var token = getUrlParameter(response,'access_token');
            $rootScope.user.sc_token=token;
            soundcloud.generateAuthString();
            SC.get("/me"+soundcloud.authString).then(function(response){
                // ...
            });
        }
```

note `getUrlParameter()` is just a custom function to get the param

Comment: How did bypass CORS restrictions? Interesting solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Make this your onload function, Soundcloud's API hasn't been updated.

```
<body onload="window.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
```

Comment: window.opener.SC.connectCallback still reference something null since the app is opened